# Dúvida com arquivo htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Olá, pessoal!

Estou com uma dúvida em relação ao meu arquivo .htaccess.
Acontece que tenho um site em duas versões, comum e mobile. Na pasta do arquivo mobile, existe o arquivo .htaccess que recebe o seguinte codigo:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera\ mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.meusite.com.br/ [L,R=302]
```

Desta forma, ao tentar acessar o link "http://meusite.com.br/mobile" através de um desktop, por exemplo, ele é direcionado para a url principal.

Até aí tudo bem.

O problema está no inverso. Na pasta raiz do site, no arquivo .htaccess coloquei da seguinte forma:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera\ mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.meusite.com.br/mobile [L,R=302]
```

Com isso, o usuário ao tentar acessar o link principal através de um móvel, deveria ser direcionado para o diretorio mobile, mas não está funcionando.

Há algum erro neste arquivo?

Abçs

Answer (score 0):

Faz assim no `htaccess` da versão web

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
   RewriteRule ^$ http://m.example.com/ [L,R=302]
</IfModule>
```

só muda o link da url de redirecionamento
uso este em um site meu e está ok

Comment: Olá Jasar, fiz da forma que sugeriu. Ao abrir a url padrão através de um mobile, funcionou perfeitamente, redirecionando para a versão mobile. O problema é que ao testar no desktop, ele também direciona para o mobile.

Comment: estranho acabei de testar aqui e ta normal. vc testou com quais navegadores?